# Ошибка в PHP после переноса и обновления сервера Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in

Tags: php, массивы

php 7.4 помогите найти причину нескольких ошибок:

1. Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in
2. Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

В первой ошибке ссылается на первую строку:```

```
if (is_array($time_slots[$dt1_formatted]) && isset($time_slots[$dt1_formatted]) && sizeof($dt1_formatted) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($time_slots[$dt1_formatted] as $index => $time)
            {
                if (isset($day_slots[$time]))
                {
                    $day_slots[$time]["status"] = "free";
                }
            }
        }
```

Во втором случае на нее же и 2 строки формирующие header  файле index.php
private function sendSuccessJsonResponse($response)

```
    Header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
    Header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая ошибка вам явно говорит в чём проблема: "Параметр должен быть массивом или обьектом, который реализует Countable(Название интерфейса. Досл.: Исчисляемый)". Т.е. вы передате в `sizeof` что-то что нельзя посчитать. Могу предположить что `$dt1_formatted === null`. Почему? Нужно смотреть до этого в коде происходит.

Вторая ошибка так же предельно ясно указывает на проблему: "Не могу изменить заголовки - заголовки уже отправлены". Такое произошло из-за того что вместе с ошибкой сервер отправил и заголовки. Заголовки в ответе идут перед телом ответа, поэтому это вполне логичное поведение. Проблема исчезнет когда будет исправлена первая ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, буду искать, но выше вроде все выводы собираются в массив, а dt1_formatted не должен быть null, так как за ним скрывается дата '$dt1_formatted = date_format($dt1, "Y-m-d");' все данные выгружаются через api также массивами. Параллельно работает такой же скрипт с небольшими модификациями и он ошибок не выдает, попробую их построчно сравнить, может найду ошибку.

Comment: @LeoM., ну так string не является исчисляемым([`date_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.format.php) возвращает его). [Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0704a275e2147a3525f80f65f36a7241d69b0fed)